# Email is not Verified on SES even account is on Production

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My account is on production. I am using my yahoo account to send an email to any recipient. Would it be possible to use any account not under verified domain to send email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you either need to verify individual email addresses, or verify the entire domain (different procedure depending on the which you choose) - and you won't be able to verify a domain like yahoo.com which you don't own, so your only choice is to verify your individual yahoo email address and then can only send from that email addresses.

You can verify multiple single email addresses without a problem as well.

(and In case I didn't read your question right - the verification only apples to the email addresses you are sending FROM, not the email addresses you are sending TO.)

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. Yes you read it right.

Comment: By the way, the sender's email is verified on email addresses in ses also the recipient, but I am receiving an email "An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:" from mailer-daemon. What would be the problem with this?